# Can sgen.exe be used for web.config file to improve performance and cold start?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, cold-start

.NET cold start is a known issue, and it denotes the time necessary for the first time load an ASP.NET web site, which includes DLL loading, JIT compilation, w3wp.exe creation, and other stuff.

Does using sgen.exe on web.config files have an improvement effect on **cold start**?

More fundamentally, can we use this tool on web.config, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say no. .config files are handled by the config api, so having used sgen on them, the api wouldn't know how to use your compiled code.

You'd be better off looking at aspnet_compiler.exe to pre-build the site. This would have a much greater impact on the cold start delay.

Simon